# Converted the CSV into HTML file but how to highlight the Columns with colors for success and failure in email body

Tags: html, bash, awk

I have the following bash script to convert csv file into html but i want to highlight the success box in green color and Failure in red color while sending email

**check1.csv**

```
heading,heading1
test1,success
test2,success
test3,Failure
test4,sucess
```

**bash script**

```
tmp=/home/test/check1.html
awk -F',' 'BEGIN {print "<html><body><table width=500 border=2 cellspacing=2 cellpadding=2 border-collapse=collapse><font Size="2" face=\"gisha\"><col width="150">"} NR == 1 { print "<tr style=\"width=150\" bgcolor=\"#FAD7A0\">"; for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) print "<td><b>" $i "</b></td>"; print "</tr>"} NR > 1 { print "<tr style=\"width=150\">"; for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) print "<td>" $i "</td>"; print "</tr>"} END {print "</col></font></table></body></html>"}' "/home/test/check1.csv > "$tmp"
```

Please help how to highlight that box in colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following awk script (file name: "mkh.awk")

```
BEGIN   { FS=",";
          print "<html><head><style>table {font: 3ex gisha}"
          print ".green {border: 2px solid green; color:green}"
          print ".red {border: 2px solid red; color:red}"
          print "td:first-child {width:150px}</style></head>"
          print "<body><table width=500 border=2 cellspacing=2 cellpadding=2 border-collapse=collapse>"}
NR == 1 { print "<tr bgcolor=\"#FAD7A0\">";
          for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) print "<td><b>" $i "</b></td>"; 
          print "</tr>"} 
NR > 1  { print "<tr>"; 
          for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) 
            print "<td" (i==2? " class=" ($i=="Failure"?"red":"green"):"") ">" $i "</td>"; 
          print "</tr>"}
END     { print "</table></body></html>"}
```

should do the trick. I have taken most of the above code directly from the OP above. Most of it is printing out HTML and CSS code. The crucial change I made in it was maybe:

```
"<td" (i==2? " class=" ($i=="Failure"?"red":"green"):"") ">"
```

This is a "ternary operator" (very similar to the one in C or JavaScript), applied in a two level way ("one within the other"). For more details about awk, check the [manual pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk). Just a hint: `i` is the field number in one line while `$i` is the content of that field.

Apart from that I tried to replace direct formatting HTML-directives with some CSS directives at the top.

The HTML generated with it by applying the command

```
awk -f mkh.awk t.txt
```

can be seen below:

```html
<html><head><style>table {font: 3ex gisha}
.green {border: 2px solid green; color:green}
.red {border: 2px solid red; color:red}
td:first-child {width:150px}</style></head>
<body><table width=500 border=2 cellspacing=2 cellpadding=2 border-collapse=collapse>
<tr bgcolor="#FAD7A0">
<td><b>heading</b></td>
<td><b>heading1</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test1</td>
<td class=green>success</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test2</td>
<td class=green>success</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test3</td>
<td class=red>Failure</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test4</td>
<td class=green>sucess</td>
</tr>
</table></body></html>
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain your code, so that those of us that don’t speak awk can understand what it’s doing, and why/how? I can *sort* of parse parts of it, but I wouldn’t be able to apply this code to any other problem without some fairly in-depth searching.

Comment: I hope my additions above are helpful to you. `awk` is an "ancient" - yet very powerful - unix tool I learnt to work with about 30 years ago ... It ist not surprising that it is not that widely known anymore.